# Docker - Failed to fetch, Bad request

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a php image with the necessary extensions, but when it tries to download the libssl archive it fails with a 400 error.

Here is the error I am getting

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2u-1~deb9u2_amd64.deb  400  Bad Request [IP: 151.101.0.204 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried using apt-get update and --fix-missing, neither seemed to work.
I am also able to access the specified archive on my computer without issue, so I don't understand why the docker is unable to download the file

And here is my Dockerfile so far

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions calendar exif gd gettext intl mcrypt mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql shmop sockets sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm wddx xdebug xsl zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try and isolate the extension that was causing the error, but whenever I would remove an extension it wouldn't work, if i removed multiple at a time, sometimes it would work. I eventually tried cutting the list in half and seeing if that worked. Both half's were able to be built on their own.

I decided to split the list of extensions into two declarations so my Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/master/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions calendar exif gd gettext intl mcrypt mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql && \
    install-php-extensions shmop sockets sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm wddx xdebug xsl zip
```